# Android tablet to access localhost site

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am very new to Android programming. I was trying to access database connection for Android via SQL Server and PHP (Server side).

Now , I am able to connect to do a work on the local machine via Emulator using the locahost.
But I am not able to do that connection while connecting the Android tablet via USB cable to check the application on actual Android device.

Is there any way, I can access localhost on my Android tablet via USB cable. Just as how it work with 10.0.2.2 along with the Emulator.

Any help or comments would be great !!!

Comment: It is not regarding the code. Just simply access the localhost website (say through Apache or IIS) in Android device with connection through the USB

Comment: That's weird. If u have Internet permission and server IP address u should be able to

Comment: @Sajit , Yes it is . But is there any way you can host IIS freely (for SQL Server and PHP) . Well I was trying , has any body actually done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Connecting with USB cable to your machine does not put your android device on the computer's network.
If your system (the system hosting the localhost server) is on a network, try connecting the device on to the network using WIFI.

In one HTC phone, i saw the option **Reverse Tethering** when connected to the system. If your device supports reverse tethering then you can connect your android device using this mode. This will enable the device to be on the same network as your computer.

FYI, when doing this, if you try connecting to localhost it will not work, you have to specify the IP address of your system.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong.
Yes, you can. I just did the same. Using easy EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11.exe
The trick is you must first add your local ip address to the Apache server to listen to it.

Right click on the tray icon, go to "Configuration" -> "Apache" in the "httpd.config"

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 192.168.0.201:80  <<-- ADD THIS LINE
```

Then go to your Control Panel and deactivate your Windows Firewall or add your Smartphone/Tablet Ip Address to the exception.

That's it. I hope it helps.

The IP Address 192.168.0.201 may be different from yours. 192.168.0.X